# Read Status - Interop.Domino.dll

Tags: lotus-notes

Lotus Notes 8.5.2, client side without the Domino Designer license, VB.Net, VS2010, WinForms

I'm using Interop.Domino.dll to read the messages in a folder and I am able to read the values OK.

Is there a way I can tell if the Domino.NotesDocument is marked as Read?

Is there a way I can mark a document Read?

Move a document to another folder?

Comment: Domino Designer client is free.  It wasn't always free, but it's been that way for a few years now.  There's no license necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have version 8 or above,

The [GetRead](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETREAD_METHOD_DOC.html) method will tell you if the NotesDocument is read or not

The [MarkRead](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_MARKREAD_DOCUMENT.html) and [MarkUnread](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_MARKUNREAD_DOCUMENT.html) methods will allow you to change that status.

Comment: I don't have the designer license... I don't see these methods on the client .DLL. My guess is changing an existing document is not possible without the designer license. I have been able to create notes from scratch and send them, but all I have been able to do so far is read (text) from existing documents.

Comment: There is no designer license.  See my comment on your post above.  However, it is the case that some of the methods in the Domino back-end classes are not exposed through the COM interface, which is what the Interop DLL is based on.  Unfortuantely, the documentation does not always specify which methods are exposed or not.  Anyhow, I don't know if that's the case here, but it's possible.  The bigger problem with the Interop and underlying COM API is the fact that IBM does not support either of them on win64. (It can be made to work, mostly, but you're on your own if you have problems.)

Comment: I am on Win 64. I think I can accomplish what I am trying to do (write a program to processes incoming messages from a web form tool (JotForm)) by using the exposed PutInFolder() and Remove methods. I was able to move a document to another folder and follow that with a RemoveFromFolder() to move it out of the incoming queue.

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer is correct for LotusScript, the functions stated above are *not* exposed in the COM interface.

The only solution I found for setting the read-status is to Save the Document with the "bMarkread" flag. But this would fail if you dont edit anything so my solution was just setting the Subject again:

```
doc.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", doc.GetFirstItem("Subject").Text);
bool success = doc.Save(false, false, true); //here, the third param sets the read-flag
```

Hope this helps some folks, who stumble into the same issue.